# iOS 10 - Black navigation bar when first transitioning to WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios10

I am experiencing weird bug on `iOS 10.0 Simulator`.
I am using `8.0 beta (8S128d)`.

I have some places in my app where I use `WKWebView` in order to present a web page. For some reason, **first** (and only first) transition to those views makes navigation bar black. I can see the transition starting and freezing for a moment, then a black navigation bar appears. When I go back and go to that view again, everything works.

[image]